# Acquiring the scan data from a barcode scanner Wedge, Simulation to AJAX serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, barcode-scanner

I have a web application ASP MVC C#, and the users have a scanner at the desktop. They perform scans of goods.

Please help understand, *how to connect with the scanner* and acquire the scan from the user (is this a twain like driver standard)?

1. How exactly, can you I get the scan data to my application, its a simple barcode.
2. Is there a standard, or a protocol that I can register to read.
3. Is there a framework that works well with scanners

Update 1: 
How can I control whether the data shows up/scans to the text field or simply sent to a backend AJAX post childAction, for e.g. 
`[post] public .. PostedScanData(string ScannnedData) {..`  can you please share a sample if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a simple barcode scanner wil 'emulate' a keyboard/keypad and 'type' the numbers as they were typed on a keyboard. So when scanning, be sure a TextBox is selected.

Comment: Oh great, I also found keyboard emulation, wedge sending it to the page. Does it put in a text field, I am wondering how to send this data via an ajax call back and not the input text field.

Comment: @Everest depends on the specific scanner, the cheap ones are just virtual keyboards and you can't do anything with them that you can't do with typing on a keyboard. More expensive ones have special SDKs that let you intercept the input before it gets typed as a keyboard but those are device specific. It all depends on the specific device, there is no general purpose capture standard like TWIAN.

Comment: The scanner will type numbers, just like the keyboard. So if you want to capture the numbers, just create a text field and use a submit button to send the numbers to the server. like a normal Form.

Comment: so, to send it to the server... in the `ASP MVC Web APP` ,.. I understand a hidden text field with a submit. But who is responsible, who will trigger the submit, the scanner? if they are scanning 15 to 10 items continuously , how will this get there..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain any suggestions on the scanners. The Motorola, Mapjects and Honeywell ones are too expensive, we looked at all of them. I need something working fairly quick for a farmers market, what would I be looking to spend (range) and which one is easy to integrate

Comment: If the barcodes are the same length, you could trigger the submit after a certain count of numbers.